# A less hostile word that can replace "violation"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am working with a large open source software project whose code base has to be GNU Public License version 2 (GPLv2).  We have to make sure that the "stuff" that goes into the project from our volunteer contributors has a license that is compatible with the project.  I am setting up an issue tracker to track potential problems.  The most severe problems are currently tagged with the word "Violation" and the guide for contributors explains it like this:

> Violation: This means that the problem with your contribution is regarded as unequivocal and that immediate action to repair the situation is requested.  A contribution with a public license that is *not* compatible with the GPLv2 will typically have this component, as will a contribution that illegally bundles files belonging to a 3rd party (i.e. bundles such files without permission).

Objections has been raised and another word has to replace "Violation". Quote:

> "Violation" assumes malintent. I would expect contributors to react defensively/combatively if they're pointed to a tracker about their contribution with the word "violation" in it. It is more than likely that they are merely confused by the GPL's litany of rules, not intentionally trying to get away with cheating.

I would like to keep the guidance text, but replace the word "Violation" with something less hostile.

That is, the replacement word should not *imply*, but not completely rule out, malintent.

If possible, the word should be a noun, and it should convey that the problem is *not* open for discussion, and that some *action* on part of the contributor is required (all this is probably too much to ask of a single word, but I hope it indicates what I am looking for).

I did an online search for synonyms before asking here, and ended up with the following list: *abuse, contravention, encroachment, infraction, infringement, misdemeanor, negligence, offense, transgression* - all of which sound too hostile for my use case.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest and what did not suffice there? Infringement?

Comment: 'Violation' _usually_ refers to malintent, but not necessarily so. 'Violation of Ross constraints' hardly conjures up images of evil hordes (even among ELU regulars). ODO lists 'lack of compliance with' amongst its suggested synonyms. Though you probably _are_ best avoiding the word because of the heavy hint of hostile intent. But this could have been answered by looking up 'violation' in ODO.

Comment: @FreeRadical It could be that there is no non-hostile variant, either because there's a gap that hasn't been filled, or because the concept itself is negative and there's no alternative. Usually there are euphemistic ways of saying many negative things but they eventually become negative themselves, slipping down the euphemism treadmill.

Comment: (by the way, I think 'infringement' isn't hostile and doesn't assume any intent by the committer.)

Comment: @Mitch. infringement: the action of breaking the terms of a law, agreement, etc. It is a legal term, and thus (IMHO) worse than "violation".

Comment: Your whole question is predicated on a faulty understanding of the word "violation". "Breaking the terms of a law" implies malintent as much as falling through a glass window (breaking the glass) implies malintent.

Comment: @CanisLupus, you may be right, but that's irrelevant here. My job is to make an issue tracking system without pissing off our contributors. I am not tasked with educating them so that they correctly  understand the word "violation".

Comment: The word infringement should not offend or at least not more than is necessary since it refers to any reason for noncompliance with an agreement (the G.P.L.) or the law (copyright infringement). These are unavoidable concepts in the body of the text, since that is its exact subject. Yes violation and encroachment are included as possible in the definition but so is simple nonfulfillment (I'm referencing Webster's Revised Unabridged 1913) so I believe you might be assigning too much weight to it. The phrase "mere infringement" comes to mind. I'd suggest speaking it over with law experts too.

Comment: Why not tag with the intentionally non-specific word "problem", in this case, `license-problem`? That can handle a wider range of cases and avoid placing blame.

Comment: A policy violation can simply be labeled "**an issue**": a very unmarked term.

Comment: Why not search existing experts sites for what they use. Like this: https://opensource.guide/legal/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**[Noncompliance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noncompliance)** should work here.

[Compliant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compliant):

> 2. Compatible with or following guidelines, specifications, rules, or
>      laws. <sub>(Wiktionary)</sub>
>
> *The browser is standards compliant.*
>
> *The workplace is compliant with the Americans with Disabilities Act.*

**EDIT:** To further reduce the linguistic baggage, you could tag it `noncompliant-code`. That way, it's unambiguously clear to the contributors that it's their *code* that's noncompliant. Not them.

Comment: +1 for this suggestion. It is certainly better than "Violation", but it carries some negative vibes: Webster offers this example: "a perpetually incompliant employee who seemed to think that the rules did not apply to him"

Comment: @FreeRadical: Note that nonncompliant people and noncompliant software are not `compliant` in different senses. (#1 and #2 respectively from the wiktionary link)

Comment: Don't use wiktionary. People will (and have) put anything in there. 'incompliance' is an error. ['Noncompliance' is the word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noncompliance%2C+incompliance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @TusharRaj, I think most contributors tagged with "Noncompliance" would feel that the tag applied to them as well (i.e. not only to their software).

Comment: @Mitch Are we allowed to use AHDEL, Collins, M-W, Dictionary.com
... ? The ones I've mentioned all indicate that " 'incompliance' is an error" is an error. They don't even flag for 'rare'. (Though I'd choose 'noncompliance' as the more common option.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: And the plot thickens. Thank you. I feel less stupid now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's no 'allow' here, there's just trustworthiness. In the past couple months I've seen more references to wiktionary, and many of the words referenced there seem to be words that any English teacher word use red pen on. Wiktionary says nothing about register or frequency. OED says it is rare. Also, check out my NGrams link, 'incompliance' is rare. Sometimes there really are mistakes.

Comment: +1 And as suggested in your definition, OP might consider *incompatibility*.

Comment: @bib: Thanks. `Incompatibility` definitely has no hostile connotations, which would appeal to the OP. However, in programming, incompatibility is generally used in context of a device/browser etc, rather than that of a standard.

Comment: @Mitch 'Rare' and 'an error' are defined differently in any dictionary.

Comment: @FreeRadical: In that case, why not tag it something like `noncompliant-code`

Comment: @TusharRaj. Yup, "noncompliant-code" is even better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you think 'incompliant' is in free variation/appears as often as 'noncompliant'?  Is it 'indecisive' or 'undecisive'?

Comment: @Mitch I'll accept "incompliant is 'incorrect' " when a dictionary flags it as 'obsolete'; I wouldn't have picked up on this point if I'd found even one 'archaic'. Too many people are ready to pronounce judgements on these things without sufficient research; AHDEL etc have teams paid to investigate frequencies of use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure, there is some blind trust to be given to authorities like AHDEL (with the expectation of scholarship) but I can't give that to Wiktionary, and google NGrams seem to contradict both ('incompliance' is still very rare). So my trust in AHDEL has gone down. So would you suggest 'incompliant' equally with 'noncompliant'? Would you suggest using incompliant to a foreign language learner? If not, then the dictionaries should say something to that effect.

Comment: So would you suggest 'incompliant' equally with 'noncompliant'? _I've answered that._ /  Would you suggest using incompliant to a foreign language learner? _This is ELU_. / Now let me ask one. Is 'not used very often, and _non-compliant_ is the far more common term' the same as 'an error'? So why didn't/don't you use the truer version?

Comment: My habit is to leave questions open for 48 hours before picking the best answer. Still 6 hours left.

Answer (score 11):

**Infraction** is often considered less severe than violation.
[FindLaw](http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-law-basics/infractions.html):

> An infraction, sometimes called a petty offense, is the violation of an administrative regulation, an ordinance, a municipal code, and, in some jurisdictions, a state or local traffic rule. In many states an infraction is not considered a criminal offense and thus not punishable by incarceration. Instead, such jurisdictions treat infractions as civil offenses.

Comment: While an "infraction" is indeed less severe than a "violation", I'd rather stay clear of legal terms that implies wrong-doing.

Comment: @FreeRadical Sure, there's a balance you're trying to strike. I'm just not certain where it is.

Comment: infraction is a legal word, regardless.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps *[nonconformance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nonconformance)*

> a failure to conform to standard norms of behaviour

*Collins*

Similarly, *[nonconformity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonconformity)*

> Failure or refusal to conform to a prevailing rule or practice.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The latter seems a bit more willful. (But I still like @Tushar Raj's *noncompliance*)

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky because you are not looking for a general synonym of 'Violation', you are looking for a word that can be used as a Tag against issues that implies the issue is a "violation of agreement, nonconformance to rules and mandatory remedial action required"

I propose "Nonlicensable", being the negative of the adjectival form of the word ['License'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/license)

> **Noun**
>
> 1 - formal permission from a governmental or other constituted authority to do something, as to carry on some business or profession.
>
> 2 - a certificate, tag, plate, etc., giving proof of such permission; official permit: 
>   a driver's license.
>
> 3 - permission to do or not to do something.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Whilst this is not a synonym of Violation, it does accurately describe the issues you are trying to tag

Comment: How can this word possibly mean person has done a no-no??

Answer (score 3):

**Oversight**

> an unintentional failure to notice or do something

I believe making the assumption that the contributor "missed" the rule would be well received.  Even if negative intent was there, the code was flagged.  It still suggests that something can be done to come into compliance.

In its alternate definition, it means someone else is responsible for reviewing the submission.  If an item were flagged under that connotation, it would mean that the responsible party will not assume responsibility for this portion in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

As a person in this field, I typically don't see violation, as you're right, it sounds almost personal. What I normally see is something like Warning, Critical Error, Red Flag, or Action Required. Personally I would also take out the bit about "unequivocal", and maybe warn the submitter that their submission will not be processed until they fix it (if this is the case):

> **Critical Error**: Your submission cannot be processed. Immediate action to repair the situation is requested. A contribution with a public license that is not compatible with the GPLv2 can be the cause for this error message, as will a contribution that illegally bundles files belonging to a 3rd party (i.e. bundles such files without permission).

I suppose Action Required would be the most neutral if that's what you're going for.

Comment: There may be other critical errors or instances where an action is required. We use "critical" to tag severity of the problem, not the type of problem. A contribution with coding bugs that break the project is tagged "critical", but its type will be "coding bug", *not* "violation" of project license or copyright.

Comment: Critical error? Halt and Catch Fire. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Breach**

noun

An infraction or violation, as of a law, trust, faith, or promise.

(Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/breach)

Answer (score 1):

"Help!"

You don't want to imply that the problem is the contributors' fault, but you need them to help with *your* problem, which is getting the license business straightened out.  And you want to say that it is an urgent, critical problem for you (but not for your contributors).  So you have to talk about *your* problem, not what they have or haven't done.  You need their help urgently.

Answer (score 0):

**Exception**

> something excepted (objected to); an instance or case not conforming to the general rule. (Dictionary.com)

I would suggest calling these *licensing exceptions*.

Comment: This is a fairly neutral noun (which is good). However, an "exception"  is often just noted, not acted upon. The first part of the definition, "something excepted", generally means something that is excepted *from* conforming.

Comment: You need to get a dictionary and start looking words up. An *exception* is not necessarily *accepted*. The whole software world deals with *exceptions handlers* that do something about exceptions besides notice them.

Comment: I am not saying that an exception is *always* accepted. I'm saying that the notion that something is outside the norm, but tolerated, is *one* of the general meanings of the term. I also find your remark about getting a dictionary unnecessarily condescending.

Comment: something excepted is not English.

Answer (score 0):

**Accident**

> an undesirable or unfortunate happening that occurs unintentionally and usually results in harm, injury, damage, or loss; casualty; mishap: (Dictionary.com)

Eliminates the connotation of malintent completely.

---

*Or alternatively,*

**Accidental Violation**

Minimizes the implication of malintent.

Comment: But is wrong in case of an intentional violation.

Answer (score 0):

**Contravention**

I see that in your search for synonyms the thesaurus turned up the word *contravention*. I'm curious as to why this doesn't fit the bill. It would have been my first choice for a noun alternative to *violation*. In my opinion a contravention carries much less of a connotation of malicious intent than violation. Of all the options presented here I think that it fits best.

Comment: It is a legal term that implies legal wrong-doing. contravention: an action which offends against a law, treaty, or other ruling.

Answer (score 0):

"There is a critical problem with your submission"?

"Critical" implies "must be fixed", while "problem" is about as neutral as you can get without veering into ludicrous circumlocution.

Comment: There may be other critical problems. We use "critical" to tag severity of the problem, not the type of problem. A contribution with coding bugs that break the project is tagged "critical", but its type will be "coding bug", *not* "violation" of project license or copyright.

Answer (score 0):

You have a situation that is unacceptable and needs to be fixed, and there is no way around this. You want a word that clearly says that. Use any of the many more "polite" words here, and after a week someone will tell you "why didn't you still accept my contribution after a week delay", after two weeks they will tell you that since it's only an infraction/contravention/exception etc. you should let it pass, and four weeks later the person actually figures out that their contribution was unacceptable and does something about it.

Being polite is very impolite if it causes inconvenience because you didn't express the seriousness of the situation.

Comment: We're not going to just tag it. There will also be a message attached to the issue spelling out why we're unable to accept the contribution and a very concrete requirement regarding what action the contributer needs to take (in most cases the action will be to removal of the noncompliant materials from the contribution). However, I don't want a tag that implies *intentional wrongdoing* on part of the contributor.

Comment: @FreeRadical **flagged issue**.

Answer (score 0):

Your contribution is ***[incongruous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incongruous)***.

> Not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of something:
>
> "the duffel coat looked incongruous with the black dress she wore underneath"
>
> Reference: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incongruous

The word is not a common one but I believe the meaning to be quite in line with what you want to express.

Answer (score 0):

**Surprise Misuse**.

While unlikely to be accepted by the legal team, this term (by similarity with well known "*surprise [blah]*" internet memes) will suggest to most technical users that the gentler term used should be considered to have a heavy negative amplifier: your actual meaning of "violation" should be clear to most.